# How to separate the SDK from the Xcode and SDK bundle downloaded from Apple developer portal

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I downloaded Xcode 4 and iOS SDK 4.3 bundle from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#. It's a dmg file and I am wondering if there is a way to find out where the iOS SDK is in the dmg file and copy it down to local disk? Anyone has tried that before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have tried that when I was trying to build an unofficial iOS toolchain on Linux (with success, by the way).

You have to mount the DMG - the best option for that is double-clicking the DMG in Finder or typing

```
hdiutil attach filename.dmg
```

to a command line.

When you have mounted the file, you'll see a bunch of directories - I don't remember to the exact path, but there should be a directory named Packages. In there, you'll find a dozen of files with the extension `.pkg`. Actually, these are [XAR archives](http://code.google.com/p/xar/) which contain GZip archives, which in turn contain [`cpio`](http://www.gnu.org/software/cpio/) archives.

After having extracted the ones you feel logical (look for iPhoneOS4.3.sdk.pkg and the compilers [clang, GCC] as well), you will have the essential components of the iOS SDK, namely: the toolchain (containing the clang and GCC compilers and the necessary tools, including an assembler, linker and the GNU debugger, GDB) and the headers, frameworks and libraries (for example, UIKit, Foundation, libSystem, libsqlite3).

From now on, you shall be able to write simple makefiles and compile iOS apps without the need for using Xcode.

Comment: How do you mount the file in Linux?